# What is javascript:;?

Tags: javascript, html, href

In some sites I noticed the following `href`:

```
<a href="javascript:;">Link</a>
```

I'm interested in what `javascript:;` means? Is it the same as `javascript:void(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javascript:` means "*whatever comes after this will be javascript.*"

`;` ends the javascript statement.

Therefore yes, it does absolutely nothing.

**Why not just use `<a href="#">foo</a>` then?**

Simply put, using `#` will have bad consequences if you've set a `<base>` HTML tag, and in most cases it will scroll to the top of the page unless you have `onclick="return false;"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official specification of javascript: URLs, but HTML5 tries to define them, too. The [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#javascript-protocol) is rather technical, but it boils down to saying that if the script does not return anything, then following the link corresponds to getting a [204 No Content](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5). This means that “if the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent”, i.e. nothing happens.

The `void` operator returns `undefined`, so in this context, there is no difference between `void(0)` and the empty statement `;`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is the as `javascript:void(0)` and `javascript:void 0`.
This link just do nothing.